# How to upgrade a plugin for phonegap 2.5 to the latest version 3.1? and what is flow for adding an additional plugin to phonegap

Tags: javascript, jquery, cordova

```
$('#sendSms').click(function(e){
    alert("sendSms on progress");//After this alert I got continuuous errors,I can't found the reason for it
var smsInboxPlugin = cordova.require('cordova/plugin/smsinboxplugin');
smsInboxPlugin.isSupported ((function(supported) {
    if(supported) {
      alert("SMS supported !");
      window.location.href="sms:phonenum?body=haiii";
    } else
      alert("SMS not supported");
  }), function() {
    alert("Error while checking the SMS support");
  });
```

Here is ma link for the plugin I used [Pyo25 / Phonegap-SMS-reception-plugin](http://github.com/Pyo25/Phonegap-SMS-reception-plugin#aborting-a-broadcast)
I have corrected all java class error's but the problem persists...
I always got the error Uncaught module cordova/plugin/smsinboxplugin not found:56

Comment: Please remove your mobile number from ur sample bug code..

Answer (score 0):

The error means that cordova is not able to find the required functions.

For using any plugin, you should include the .js file before using any of its functions and after including cordova.js file in the html file.

Also how did you added the plugin to your project? It's always recommended to add a new plugin via CLI tool.

Comment: Its a plugin for 2.5 version so I added the java files into the src portion and js files to the page itself. But it wont work properly